# Is there an API to get which user groups are assigned to a certain application in Google Workspace?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

In Google Workspace admin console, we can configure SSO for applications, and assign user groups to the application.

The group assignment can be checked using the following way:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/9050643?hl=en#step5&zippy=%2Csee-the-services-and-organizational-units-for-access-groups%2Cstep-check-service-access

Is there any api to retrieve this group assginment information?
I don't see any in Google Workspace Admin API.

Comment: Hi, can you provide the documentation related to `group assginment information`, in order to clarify which feature you are interested in? Is it [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/11143403?hl=en)?

Comment: https://support.google.com/a/answer/9050643?hl=en
I think it should be this.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

There's currently no API in Admin SDK that will retrieve this information.

#### Feature request:

If you're interested in this feature, I'd suggest you to request it on Issue Tracker using [this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102).